# Background: url() não vai

Tags: html, css

Quero adicionar uma imagem na minha pagina, ja tentei de duas formas, com background: url(img/menina.png); e background-image: url(img/menina.png);

A foto esta na pagina correta, a foto esta no formato correto, o css esta linkado com o html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />

<title>Criativa</title>
```

```
<section class="header">

</section>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

```
.header {
width: 150px;;
background: url(img/menina.png);
background-image: url(img/menina.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você precisa colocar valores no `width` e `height` quer permitam que a imagem apareça, como no exemplo que adicionei experimente remover o atributo `height` ela some.

```css
.header {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(https://www.conversion.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/google-icone.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">

</section>
```